# Step down transformer connection with stepper motor drive

Tags: stepper-motor

I have to connect a step down transformer to a stepper motor drive. This transformer has 3 wires that i must connect to the driver. I'm having difficulty in making the connections. Any help would be appreciated!
[image: Transformer image]
[image: Transformer image]
[image: Stepper drive]
Thanks!

Comment: Green is earth, red and black *should* be hot and neutral; since it's an isolation transformer it shouldn't matter. A simple ohm check can be use to verify that

Comment: What kind of AC power outlet is that? Which country?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make the necessary connections and it works. The country its from is India.